# How to change Paypal dropdown to radio buttons?

Tags: html, css, paypal

How can i change paypal dropdown options to radio buttons? I really have no idea and i have tried different methods but none of them isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the dropdown can't be changed to radio button. dropdown is the only way recognize by our system.